# HBase Lily Indexer High Availability

Tags: hadoop, hbase, indexer

I'm looking for a solution to make the Hbase lily indexer high Availabile.

Thanks =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Finally found an answer, In the HBase lily indexer there is no single point of failure, the simple fact of running multiple instances is sufficient and will also share the work of indexing over the nodes cause it's based on the hbase replication.